# Windows 11, block all programs except chosen ones

Tags: windows, windows-11

I am trying to find a way to block all program/executables on my computer except specific ones. I have a tendency to get distracted when I am supposed to study, so I want to disable all applications (preferably games) so I can focus on studying.

I want to allow applications such as; discord, spotify, visual studio code and google chrome. Then everything else will not be able to start (during a set time).

Is there any programs or feature on windows where I can do this? I have been googling around but I cannot find anything.

Thanks!
Simon

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser! When you search for "block apps study windows", did you also see [this link](https://zapier.com/blog/stay-focused-avoid-distractions/)? Were all the suggestions useless there?

Comment: Set up a standard user (not admin) that does not have games installed. Make sure games were not installed for All Users.  Reinstall for one user only if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft application 'Microsoft Family Safety' allows for granular application control with scheduled limits and the ability to block individual applications during selected windows of time. While it's geared towards supporting parents in limiting their children's PC usage, it does exactly what you're asking for. The only prerequisite is that you login to your PC with your Microsoft account, not a local account.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/family-safety